# Trouble in creating the layout using dynamic views and drawable for ecommerce application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am creating an ecommerce application and I have to create the layout as I have attached in the figure. I have tried with dynamic views and drawable but I am not able to get any success.

[image: Below image attached]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look at the graphic images a little differently.

Let's take that top horizontal display (Place/Shipped/Delivered).  What if you created images like this:

Image 1:

[image: graphic1]

Image 2

[image: graphic2]

Image 3:

[image: graphic3]

Then you could divide the display into three columns, one each for Placed, Shipped, and Delivered.

Once the three columns are next to each other, the lines would join into one continuous line like the display.

Your column would look like this (pseudo-XML):

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Placed"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="20th Jan"/>

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/start_with_check"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

You could put those together in a horizontal `LinearLayout`, or even a horizontal `RecyclerView`.

For the vertical timeline at the bottom, you could use the same strategy and have a vertical `RecyclerView` that would display an arbitrary number of events.
 Once the images are stacked on top of each other, you would see a continuous vertical line.

---

Edit

So let's make it even easier to put your graphics together by separating the lines from the circles.

line_start.png:

[image: line_start]

line_continue.png:

[image: line_continue]

line_end.png:

[image: line_end]

white_check.png:

[image: white_check]

blue_check.png:

[image: blue_check]

dot.png:

[image: dot]

(Yes, there are glitches in the circles.  I did this quick and dirty to demonstrate.  That's why you have graphic designers, to do this stuff for you.)

Using PNG images with transparency -- as I did in these examples -- is required so that you can overlay the images.

Now, you can see how the first item will always have line_start, the last item will always have line_end, and all the items in between will have line_continue.

Once you have that, you can overlay your circle graphics on top of the line graphics using a `FrameLayout`. For example, here are the first three items:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Placed"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="20th Jan"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/line_start"/>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/white_check"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Shipped"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="21st Jan"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/line_continue"/>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/dot"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:text="Delivered"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="25th Jan"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/line_end"/>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/blue_check"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I showed these as preset XML, but since all the items have the same basic layout, I hope you can see how easy it would be to generate these dynamically.

Comment: kris thank your answer but If i need these horizontal lines dynamically to be created then what will you suggest in this case, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to simplify the dynamic creation of the graphics.

Comment: I will look into this as suggested by you kris, thank you for your time, I will get back to you soon.